# Sharepoint Online every SPFx web parts get this error : Something went wrong -> Mismatched anonymous define() module

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I have SharePoint online sites and some spfx web parts. These sites are created with publishing site templates and web parts have been working for months. I rarely got this error "something went wrong". When I refresh the pages then the error goes away. Every web part gets the same error. Even if I use an empty web part it gives the same error. But in last two weeks, that error increased a lot. Is there any update for publishing sites? How can I remove this error?

Something went wrong

If the problem persists, contact the site administrator and give them the information in Technical Details. TECHNİCAL DETAİLS ERROR: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(e,f,d){"use strict"; function i(e,t)...

I redeployed the packages but nothing change.

Comment: Are you referencing any 3rd part package in the web parts? What type of web part do you use, no framwork or react, typescript?

Comment: I created SPFx react web parts. If I use a community site template, these web parts work perfectly. I think it is somehow related to the publishing site template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the cause.
I use a publishing portal site template with a custom master page. There are some javascript references in the header. When I removed references, the error has gone. The final solution is to add this code

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:Scriptlink language="javscript"
name="https://....js"
runat="server" Localizable="false"/>-->
```